# MYSQL database datatype ENUM

Tags: mysql

I have column in Mysql `member_type ENUM(Admin,normal_user)` .I need to make that column work like, It should have only one `Admin` in database . So,how can i restrict user so that he/she cannot enter another `Admin`
in that column while inserting to the column.

Using `ENUM(Admin,normal_user) UNIQUE` is not working because it will take UNIQUE value for every row.

Comment: Since when does SQL Server have enums?

Comment: SQL Server does not have an `Enum` data type. Perhaps you are using MySql?